# Network Devices ( Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 ) with no drivers

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, multi-boot, kali-linux

Recently i installed Kali Linux as 2nd OS, on my Laptop ([GL552VW](https://www.asus.com/ch-de/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL552VW/)), functioning as **DualBoot**, togheter with **Microsoft Windows 10**.

Network Drivers for my Device **Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260** could not be detected, i've found some on [github](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/blob/master/realtek/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw) but it's only the LAN-Driver, i need the **Wifi-Drivers** too. This is the log

```
    [    3.854841] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.854929] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.854941] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
```

There is a quite similiar post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952028/ubuntu-16-04-1-with-kernel-4-12-10-041210-generic-intel-8260-bluetooth-not-worki/952043), but with Bluetooth, i basically need this, but for wifi.

Comment: Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) _is_ a LAN protocol.

Comment: You need to install the correct firmware, google the error message to find similar questions. As far Kali, please read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me).